# JS function not firing on button click

Tags: javascript, html, function

EDIT: The "Create New Startup" button works with the "run code snippet" button in Stack Overflow, but not with index.html in chrome...

I have a button that's not firing the JS function. 
Here's the HTML:

```
   <button onclick="chooseStartup()" id="create">Create New Startup</button>
```

And here's the JS function:

```
var startupX = ['Uber', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Apple', 'Facebook', 'Twitter'];
var startupY = ['Slack', 'Trello', 'Tesla', 'Hyperloop', 'Harvest'];

function chooseStartup() {
var x = startupX[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupX.length)];
var y = startupY[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupY.length)];

document.getElementById('startupX').innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById('startupY').innerHTML = y; 
};
```

Any idea why it's not working?

After I fix this issue, how would I go about making the favorite button save the  generated sentence -- and then clicking the print button to display all the saved favorites?

All my code is below

```js
var startupX = ['Uber', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Apple', 'Facebook', 'Twitter'];
var startupY = ['Slack', 'Trello', 'Tesla', 'Hyperloop', 'Harvest'];

function chooseStartup() {
var x = startupX[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupX.length)];
var y = startupY[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupY.length)];

document.getElementById('startupX').innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById('startupY').innerHTML = y; 
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mad Lib</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Your description goes here">
  <meta name="keywords" content="one, two, three">

  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- external CSS link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

   <h1 id="xForY"></h1>
<h1>A startup that is 
    <span id="startupX"></span>, but for 
    <span id="startupY"></span>
</h1>
  <div id="inputs">
    <button onclick="chooseStartup()" id="create">Create New Startup</button>   
    <button id="save">Favorite Startup</button>
    <button id="print">Print Favorites</button>
  </div>

  <h2 id="favorites">

  </h2>


  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/madlib-console.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you include the console output (if there is any) to help with debugging.

Comment: Do check `Dev-Tools -> Console` for errors...

Comment: No all your code is not below, as you said. Sorry :) because where you put the js function you are calling? External? Which name? Internal to the html? You seem to ripped all and put the pieces here for us to link. This way is difficult.

Comment: Console Error: index.html:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: chooseStartup is not defined

Comment: @statosdotcom Sorry to make things difficult-- Not my intention!, what can I do to make things easier?

Comment: @OwenSchifferli – Basically you have not included the script you have shared...

Comment: @statosdotcom I'm trying to call the function internal to the HTML, which I know violates seperation of concerns, but not sure how to fix it:    <button onclick="chooseStartup()" id="create">Create New Startup</button>

Comment: My apologies, its all ok Owen! I think Rayon already got that. Best!

Comment: Got the Create New Startup button working, was a directory error :/

Comment: Any suggestions on how would I go about making the favorite button save the generated sentence?

Comment: `Math.random()` has a range of 0 to 1, and 1 being exclusive, so your *random* integer is always 1. So product is just `startupX.length` and `startupY.length`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Answer (score 0):

To favorite and then print it do the following:
 **STEP 1**
Change from this:

> ```
> <button id="save">Favorite Startup</button>
> <button id="print">Print Favorites</button>
> ```

To this:

> ```
> <button onclick="doFav()" id="save">Favorite Startup</button>
> <button onclick="printFav()" id="print">Print Favorites</button>
> ```

**STEP 2**
Insert the following code on the `<script></script>` portion of your HTML:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
} return ""; }

function doFav(){setCookie('myFav','A startup that is '+document.getElementById('startupX').innerHTML+' but for '+document.getElementById('startupY').innerHTML,1);}
function printFav(){document.getElementById('favorites').innerHTML = getCookie('myFav');}
```

Then pay attention because the setting of cookies locally is disabled by default. If you try this code online you will see that it runs without errors.

Comment: @o.schiff , excuse me, had my solution working? Need help? Thank you.

Comment: O.Schiff, it's everything ok? Need some more help? Thanks.